# Enable / Disable input using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this, when I fill up the #number, the #texth is enabled (default is disabled) for me to fill it up. But when I delete content in #number. It doesn't disable #texth!

```
 function soluong_nhap()
    {
        $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
            var row = $(this).find('#number').val();
            if(row != null)
            {
                $('#texth').prop("disabled", false);
            }
            if(row == null)
            {
                $('#texth').prop("disabled", true);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: Because when you delete all content the value of #texth becomes "" (Empty string)

Comment: Thanks you guys !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you delete the content, it doesn't turn into null, it's `""`. You should add it to your condition, and also use `else`:

```
function soluong_nhap()
{
    $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
        var row = $(this).find('#number').val();
        if (row === null || row === "")
        {
            $('#texth').prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#texth').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but when text is change, should i use onkeyup or onchange ?

Comment: Yes, write the function once and save it in a variable and then register all events to that function, instead of writing it over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you delete all content the value of #texth becomes "" (Empty string)

Try this

```
function soluong_nhap()
{
    $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
        var row = $(this).find('#number').val();
        $('#texth').prop("disabled", !row);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with keyup() function.

```
$(row).keyup(function() {
 if(row != null)
            {
                $('#texth').prop("disabled", false);
            }
            if(row == null)
            {
                $('#texth').prop("disabled", true);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (row === null || row === "")
    {
        $('#texth').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#texth').prop("disabled", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to:

```
$('#texth').prop("disabled", (row === null || row === ""));
```